# NetBeans snap - Java configuration

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, snapcraft, snap

I've installed the NetBeans snap on Ubuntu 23.10. I've also installed the OpenJDK v22 snap.

When I try to run `netbeans` in my shell, I get the error:

```
Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch.
```

How can I make NetBeans aware of the openJDK snap?

The OpenJDK snap seems to be installed in the location below because when I type openjdk in my shell, I see the following:

```
/var/snap/openjdk/1735/openjdk.env
```

I already tried adding `source /var/snap/openjdk/1735/openjdk.env` to my .bashrc file to ensure that when I run `java -version` it knows that I'm using OpenJDK. This doesn't work for NetBeans though.

Related snap packages:

https://snapcraft.io/netbeans

https://snapcraft.io/openjdk

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get netbeans running by executing the following commands in the shell.

1. Setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/snap/openjdk/current/jdk
```

2.Add `Java_HOME` to the executable `PATH`

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I will add the two commands above to my `~/.bashrc` file so that those two commands are executed when starting the shell.

NOTE - This only works for the shell not the Ubuntu UI.

Related documentation:

https://github.com/jgneff/openjdk

https://snapcraft.io/openjdk